# Fedora 25, pptp connects but not working, too many transferred packets

Tags: linux, networking, fedora, networkmanager, pptp

After update to Fedora 25 one of my PPTP connections strangely works. Remote net is not available.

It is connected, successfully get remote net IP address. While connected **nothing** is available in remote net, but internet works fine. After a few minutes connection breaks by itself.

I've noticed strange thing, while pptp connection is on there are too much `TX packets` transferred:

```
ppp0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1400
        inet 192.168.1.96  netmask 255.255.255.255  destination ___.__.___.___
        ppp  txqueuelen 3  (Point-to-Point Protocol)
        RX packets 10  bytes 172 (172.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 9864041  bytes 5842982146 (5.4 GiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

In a 10-15 seconds it shows up to 5.4 GiB of packets. It grows very fast.

The same if firewalld is disabled.

I'm using Network-Manager to connect to pptp.

```
[root@c0rp ~]# lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch:cxx-4.1-amd64:cxx-4.1-noarch:desktop-4.1-amd64:desktop-4.1-noarch:languages-4.1-amd64:languages-4.1-noarch:printing-4.1-amd64:printing-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: Fedora
Description:    Fedora release 25 (Twenty Five)
Release:    25
Codename:   TwentyFive
[root@c0rp ~]# uname -a
Linux c0rp 4.10.8-200.fc25.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Mar 31 13:20:22 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Can someone help me to investigate the problem, please

---

*Update after solution was provided*

I found that newly created route points to itself, using `route` command. Check exactly after pptp connected:

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    50     0        0 ppp0
```

What I did is:

1. Remove delete assigned address from network device
2. Add back the assigned address along with a replacement peer address

Everything exactly as it was pointed in the link.

[image]

Finally I add this two steps into `dispatcher.d` script:

```
#!/bin/bash  

INTERFACE=$1
ACTION=$2
SSID="Your vpn connection name in Network Manager"

if [[ $CONNECTION_ID == "$SSID" ]]; then
        if [[ $ACTION = "vpn-up" ]]; then
                IP4_ADDRESS=$(ifconfig "$1" | grep -Eo 'inet (addr:)?([0-9]*\.){3}[0-9]*' | grep -Eo '([0-9]*\.){3}[0-9]*' | grep -v '127.0.0.1')
                ip addr del "$IP4_ADDRESS" dev $INTERFACE
                ip addr add "$IP4_ADDRESS" peer 192.168.1.9/24 dev $INTERFACE
        fi
fi
```

I put this script into `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this: http://pptpclient.sourceforge.net/howto-diagnosis.phtml#ip_loop.

`NM` (or `pppd`) is creating an additional, wrong, default route (even if `nodefaultroute` is being passed as parameter). `route del` won't delete it.

I got around it by telling NM the connection would be shared with other users.

It is most likely a bug, but this solved the problem for a while.

Comment: Thanks for the link, using it I found reliable solution.

Comment: wow, I have this problem now with NM on Fedora31